# Where can I find or add where different favicon implementations should go in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, cross-platform, liferay-6, favicon, liferay-theme

So I am able to configure one favicon per theme through this directory: `my-theme/src/main/webapp/images/favicon.ico`, but MDN recommends configuring a favicon to be sized differently for different platforms, like so:

```
<!-- third-generation iPad with high-resolution Retina display: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/static/img/favicon144.a6e4162070f4.png">
<!-- iPhone with high-resolution Retina display: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/static/img/favicon114.0e9fabd44f85.png">
<!-- first- and second-generation iPad: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/static/img/favicon72.8ff9d87c82a0.png">
<!-- non-Retina iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android 2.1+ devices: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/static/img/favicon57.a2490b9a2d76.png">
<!-- basic favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/static/img/favicon32.e02854fdcf73.png">
```

The [liferay wiki article on favicons](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+to+change+the+favorites+icon) recommends to edit `Top_Head.jsp`, but that file does not exist anywhere on my system.

I found the `portal_normal.vm` file, which *seems* to be the right place to place favicon configs like in the example above, but still not sure exactly where to put them. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of liferay are you using?

Comment: liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp17

Comment: You have to create a custom jsp hook to override top_head JSP to add these tags. Refer to this [post](https://web.liferay.com/web/daniel.tyger/blog/-/blogs/expand-your-brand-add-fav-and-touch-icon-options-to-liferay) if you are still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the file where I can put the favicon configs: `liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp17/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT/html/common/themes/top_head.jsp`

Comment: Below this line: `<link href="<%= themeDisplay.getPathThemeImages() %>/<%= PropsValues.THEME_SHORTCUT_ICON %>" rel="Shortcut Icon" />`. Where `themeDisplay.getPathThemeImages()` is your theme's `/images` folder and `PropsValues.THEME_SHORTCUT_ICON` resolves to `favicon.ico` according to `portal.properties` property `theme.shortcut.icon`.